# What are these terms in Marine Navigation ETA, DTG and TTG?

Tags: route, navigation, marine

Consider a scenario where a ship has to navigate and reach a specific destination. I have a route plan comprising of multiple route way-points through which my ship has to go through to reach its destination point. Throughout the navigation, I'm required to calculate the ETA (Estimated Time of Arrival), DTG (Distance To Go) and TTG (Time To Go).

What exactly are these terms and can you provide mathematical expressions for calculating each?

Answer (score 0):

Eta is calculated with distance divided by speed. Then you get the time your voyage will take. Example 20 nautical miles with a vessel traveling at 10knots will use 2 hours for this voyage if speed is over ground. Just add two hours to your present time and voila.